# Using map to make a list from a range

Tags: list, dictionary, lambda, range

I want to create a list of items from a range using the map command. I have the following code that's supposed to take the range between two numbers (`firstnum` and `secondnum`) and a lambda statement that says to increment between the two numbers and create `myList` of the results (between the two ends of the range). However my syntax is wrong, not sure why...

```
["myList"] = map(lambda x, y: x + 1, range(firstnum..secondnum))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be valid syntax:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x + 1, range(2, 12)))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

But you can get the same result much simpler:

```
>>> list(range(3, 13))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Or more general:

```
>>> firstnum = 2
>>> secondnum = 12
>>> (list(map(lambda x: x + 1, range(firstnum, secondnum))) == 
     list(range(firstnum + 1, secondnum + 1)))
True
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried using the last version so that gives lists of negative numbers (x - 1), so for instance firstnum = 5, secondnum = -20, but this results in an empty list instead of a list with 15 negative numbers. I'll use abs() to check if to make the list by increments or decrements, but can you say what am I doing wrong that "x - 1" results in empty lists

Comment: You need to give it a negative step: `list(range(5, -20, -1))`.